# Mongoose $lookup aggregate doesn't work as expected

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

I am writing this mean stack application and here I have a company schema and vehicle schema for that company.

company details schema

```
var CompanyDetailsSchema = new Schema({
    companyName: String,
    createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    ...............
    ...............

});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Company-details', CompanyDetailsSchema);
```

vehicle schema

```
var VehicleDetailsSchema = new Schema({
    companyId:{
        type:mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Company-details'
    },
    createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    ....................
    ....................
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Vehicle-details', VehicleDetailsSchema);
```

what I need is to get all the company details also when I get vehicle details. like in an SQL join query, for that I am using this  `$lookup` aggregate. this code sample returns all the vehicles but the company details are empty. how to get all the company details also in mongoose.

```
getVehciles:() =>{
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            VehicleDetailsSchema.aggregate([{
                $lookup: {
                    from: "Company-details", // collection name in db
                    localField: "companyId",
                    foreignField: "_id",
                    as: "companyDetails"
                }
            }]).exec(function(err, vehicles){
                if(err) {
                    reject(err)
                } else {
                    resolve(vehicles)
                }
            });
        })
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code works for me.

```
 getVehciles:() =>{
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        VehicleDetailsSchema.aggregate([{
            $lookup: {
                from: "company-details", // pass the callection name in small letters
                localField: "companyId",
                foreignField: "_id",
                as: "companyDetails"
            }
        }]).exec(function(err, vehicles){
            if(err) {
                reject(err)
            } else {
                resolve(vehicles)
            }
        });
    })
},
```

Comment: what's the difference between this and my code. can you explain what you changed please.

Comment: pass the collection name small letters like this `company-details`